# What is the relation between the female protagonists of these two manga series?

Tags: natsu-no-arashi, soredemo-machi-wa-mawatteiru

Tv Tropes states that [Soredemo Machi wa Mawatteiru](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/SoredemoMachiWaMawatteiru)<sup>1</sup> is a spiritual successor to [Natsu no Arashi!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/NatsuNoArashi)

Both female protagonists have the same surname "Arashiyama": Hotori Arashiyama ((嵐山 歩鳥) and Sayoko Arashiyama (嵐山 小夜子).

The series are written by different authors.

Is it just a coincidence or is there some relation or shoutout between the two?

<sup><sup>1</sup> A copy of the page on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150102133255/http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/SoredemoMachiWaMawatteiru), snapshot on 2015-01-02. Ctrl+F in your browser for "Spiritual Successor".</sup>

Comment: TVTropes is, let's say, not always the most accurate reference on matters like this. To be blunt, it sometimes states outright fabrications as if they're facts that everyone knows. I've been burned by this in the past.

Comment: BTW, upvoted the question, because if this is another TVTropes con job, it's good to have it debunked somewhere on the net, and if it's real, it's good to have some real evidence somewhere on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no apparent relation between the Soredemo Machi wa Mawatteiru and Natsu no Arashi manga series—they were published in different magazines and have different authors (Natsu no Arashi is by Jin Kobayashi, the author of School Rumble). From what I can tell, the stories are completely different too. (I've only seen one episode of Soredemo Machi wa Mawatteiru, and never anything of Natsu no Arashi.) But the anime versions of both shows are produced by Shaft and directed by Akiyuki Shinbou, as their Wikipedia pages point out. That's probably what the TVTropes page was referring to.

I'm not really sure how that makes Soredemo Machi wa Mawatteiru a spiritual successor to Natsu no Arashi—look at [Shinbou's filmography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiyuki_Shinbo#Director) and you could claim that, say, The Soul Taker was the spiritual successor to Twilight of the Dark Master, or Denpa Onna was the spiritual successor to Arakawa Under the Bridge, on the basis that Shinbou directed one and then later directed the other. On the other hand, the otherwise unrelated Pani Poni Dash and Negima?! do share a lot of stylistic similarities, so perhaps it's something like that.

Comment: I really love that TV Tropes has this loose "just toss in your two cents" approach, but sometimes its hard to tell the fake coins from the real ones.

Comment: @Mindwin Awesome metaphor :}